# Documenting a simple JavaScript Object in sphinx-js

Tags: javascript, python-sphinx, jsdoc

I have an object that is documented using JSDoc tags,

```
/**
 * Some description of this object.
 * @memberof Constants#
 * @readonly
 * @enum {string}
 * @property {string} CONST1 Explanation of const 1.
 * @property {string} CONST2 Explanation of const 2.
 */
 SomeObject: {
     CONST1: "const1",
     CONST2: "const2"
 },
```

When generating the docs using sphinx-js only the name, description, and the type (here it is string) is documented but there is no mention of `CONST1` or `CONST2` properties.

Is there a way that sphinx-js can show the property values of this object? Is there a workaround I can do?

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you are trying to get Sphinx to process your code.  Are you using `js:autofunction` in your rst files?  Something else?  Is this object inside a function or another object?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `sphinx-js` supports this currently.  From the project [README](https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js):

> So far, we understand and convert the JSDoc block tags @param,
>   @returns, @throws, @example (without the optional ),
>   @deprecated, @see, and their synonyms. Other ones will go poof into
>   the ether.

Unfortunately, I don't immediately see a workaround for this.